# Network traffic being automatically balanced instead of only through one interface

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-2012

I have 2 servers each with 2 network cards running through two totally separate networks.  One network is a public facing network and the NICs are configured with public IP's.  The other network is a private network connecting the two servers with private IP's.

```
Server 1 IPs:
197.189.20x.x / 255.255.255.248 / GW: 197.189.20x.x - Public NIC plugged into public network
10.10.10.1 / 255.255.255.0 / GW: None - Private NIC plugged into private network

Server 2 IPs:
197.189.21x.x / 255.255.255.248 / GW: 197.189.21x.x - Public NIC plugged into public network
10.10.10.3 / 255.255.255.0 / GW: None - Private NIC plugged into private network
```

Regardless of which IP the servers connect to each other with, the traffic is being sent through the public NIC (which is 100mb), then when it reaches it's throughput limit, it puts the additional traffic on the private NIC (which is 1gb).

To further fuel the confusion, when I disable the public nic, I get a full 1gb transfer, when I enable the public nic and it "load balances itself", then I only get around 300mb (100 from public, 200 from private).

I don't know if this will mean anything, but these two servers were replaced this week.  Previously we had two servers running Windows Server 2008 R2 with different makes of on-board NICs; the new servers have been loaded with Windows Server 2012 R2 and are running identical Intel on-board NICs.  So the network is the same, it's just the servers and their OS's that are now different.  On the two 2008 servers everything was working perfectly out the box, private traffic was private and public traffic was public.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm ready to give up and go get hammered instead!

Edit: In a desperate measure, I started regressing the servers in an attempt to try isolate the cause of the issue.  As soon as I removed the Virtual Switches from Hyper-V, the network immediately started responding as expected.  Put the switches back and it starts dynamically load balancing again.  That helped narrow my search and I found this article ["What's New in Hyper-V Virtual Switch in Windows Server 2012 R2"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn343757.aspx#bkmk_lb)

> ### Dynamic Load Balancing of Network Traffic
>
> Windows Server® 2012 provided simultaneous load distribution and
>   failover, but did not ensure load distribution between the NICs in a
>   NIC team in a balanced manner.
>
> In Windows Server® 2012 R2, dynamic load balancing continuously and
>   automatically moves traffic streams from NIC to NIC within the NIC
>   team to share the traffic load as equitably as possible.
>
> For more information on NIC Teaming, see NIC Teaming Overview.

The only kicker is, we're NOT USING NIC TEAMING! Hopefully this sheds some light on the subject and here's to hoping someone's encountered and managed to solve this dilemma.

Edit 2: Here is the routing table (Hyper-V Switches have been created again):

```
Interface List
 22...0c c4 7a 71 a9 01 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
 20...0c c4 7a 71 a9 00 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   197.189.20x.x2   197.189.20x.x3    261
       10.10.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.10.10.1    261
       10.10.10.1  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.1    261
     10.10.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.1    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
   197.189.20x.x1  255.255.255.248         On-link    197.189.20x.x3    261
   197.189.20x.x3  255.255.255.255         On-link    197.189.20x.x3    261
   197.189.20x.x4  255.255.255.255         On-link    197.189.20x.x3    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    197.189.20x.x3    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.1    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    197.189.20x.x3    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.1    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   197.189.20x.x2  Default
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   197.189.20x.x2     256
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 15   1177 ::/0                     2002:c058:6301::1
 15   1176 ::/0                     2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 15   1005 2002::/16                On-link
 15    261 2002:c5bd:cb0a::c5bd:cb0a/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

VSwitch configs for both servers are identical:

```
Private network is an "External Network" switch connected to the NIC running the private 10.x IPs.
Public network is an "External Network" switch connected to the NIC running public 197.x IPs.
No VLANs configured
```

Appreciate the assist, let me know if you need anything else, I'll be here all night :(

Comment: Can you output your routing table? I have a feeling something is amiss and your servers are using the NIC with the gateway set since they aren't aware that they are on the 10.x.x.x network. EDIT: Seen you are using HyperV switches as well, can you explain your vswitch config as well?